# r: partially reshaping to wide table but keep key column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, reshape

I would like to convert my current data frame into a wide table by spreading out `Lag` but also keep the variable `agent`. The number in most of the cells of the wide table is `sales`.

```
library(reshape2)
set.seed(123)

day = rep(seq(as.Date('2019/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/04'), by="day"), each = 5)
agent = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 20, replace = T)
sales = rnorm(20, 100, 30) 
Lag = sample(0:3, 20, replace=T)

dt = data.frame(day, sales, agent, Lag)
```

Ideally, the outcome looks like:

[image]

I tried the following but neither of these works.

```
dcast(dt, day~Lag, value.var='sales')
dcast(dt, day~Lag+agent, value.var='sales')
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at `tidyr::spread`?

Comment: What do you want to do if there is more than one match as in the case of `dt[dt$day == "2019-01-02"& dt$agent == "B", ]`?

Comment: @sindri_baldur I'll add them up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dt, day + agent ~ paste0("lag_", Lag), value.var='sales', fun.aggregate = sum)

#           day agent     lag_0     lag_1     lag_2     lag_3
# 1  2019-01-01     A   0.00000   0.00000 136.72245   0.00000
# 2  2019-01-01     B   0.00000 112.02314   0.00000   0.00000
# 3  2019-01-01     C 110.79441 103.32048   0.00000  83.32477
# 4  2019-01-02     A   0.00000 153.60739   0.00000   0.00000
# 5  2019-01-02     B   0.00000  85.81626   0.00000 235.97619
# 6  2019-01-02     C   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  41.00149
# 7  2019-01-03     A   0.00000  81.24882   0.00000   0.00000
# 8  2019-01-03     B  78.13326   0.00000  93.46075   0.00000
# 9  2019-01-03     C   0.00000   0.00000  69.21987  67.96529
# 10 2019-01-04     A   0.00000 190.98950 104.60119   0.00000
# 11 2019-01-04     C 187.01365   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Note: the package `reshape2` is falling out of use and maintenance. So it is recommended to switch to using `data.table::dcast()` instead or some other alternative such as `tidyr`.

Comment: That's perfect! Is there any chance I can substitute 0 with N/A or Null?

Comment: Sure. For example replace `fun.aggregate = sum` with `fun.aggregate = function(x) {if (length(x)) sum(x) else NA_real_}`

Comment: might want to add the `library` you used. FYI, I think `reshape2` package is getting deprecated

Comment: @Sotos this code works with both `reshape2::dcast()` version 1.4.3 and `data.table::dcast()` which I usually use and (as far as I know) is being actively maintained.

Comment: Yes, `data.table::dcast()` is fine. I just commented about reshape as the OP is using that. I suggest you add the library with a note about the data.table one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` / `tidyr` alternative. Using `spread` from `tidyr` you can generate the form you want:

```
library(tidyr)
dt %>% spread(Lag, unique(Lag))
```

Using `dplyr` you can then fill the columns accordingly:

```
dt %>% spread(Lag, unique(Lag), fill = 0) %>% mutate(`0` = sales * `0`) %>% mutate(`1` = sales * `1`) %>% mutate(`2` = sales * `2`/2) %>% mutate(`3` = sales * `3`/3)

          day     sales agent 0         1         2         3
1  2019-01-01  83.32477     C 0   0.00000   0.00000  83.32477
2  2019-01-01 103.32048     C 0 103.32048   0.00000   0.00000
3  2019-01-01 110.79441     C 0   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
4  2019-01-01 112.02314     B 0 112.02314   0.00000   0.00000
5  2019-01-01 136.72245     A 0   0.00000 136.72245   0.00000
6  2019-01-02  41.00149     C 0   0.00000   0.00000  41.00149
7  2019-01-02  85.81626     B 0  85.81626   0.00000   0.00000
8  2019-01-02 114.93551     B 0   0.00000   0.00000 114.93551
9  2019-01-02 121.04068     B 0   0.00000   0.00000 121.04068
10 2019-01-02 153.60739     A 0 153.60739   0.00000   0.00000
```

Comment: The data structure is what I want, but it seems that what's in the cell under Lag columns is the value of Lag instead of the value of sales. Is there any way I can fix it?